# Cassandra Clustering Key not able to order by

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql

I am new to cassandra and I am trying to figure out why I cannot order my logs by the created_at date.
The following are the table description, the select result and the select statement I am trying to create.

```
    cassandra@cqlsh:mytable> DESCRIBE TABLE mytable.log;

    CREATE TABLE mytable.log (
        id uuid,
        created_at timestamp,
        deleted boolean,
        level text,
        message text,
        obj text,
        obj_name text,
        origin text,
        user int,
        PRIMARY KEY (id, created_at)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC)
        AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
        AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
        AND comment = ''
        AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
        AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
        AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
        AND default_time_to_live = 0
        AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
        AND max_index_interval = 2048
        AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
        AND min_index_interval = 128
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
        AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
    CREATE INDEX deleted_idx ON mytable.log (deleted);
    CREATE INDEX level_idx ON mytable.log (level);
    CREATE INDEX message_idx ON mytable.log (message);
    CREATE INDEX origin_idx ON mytable.log (origin);
    CREATE INDEX user_idx ON mytable.log (user);

    cassandra@cqlsh:mytable> SELECT *  FROM mytable.log  WHERE "created_at" <= '2015-04-29 00:00:00' AND "user" = 20 LIMIT 10;

     id                                   | created_at               | deleted | level | message | obj                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                | obj_name | origin          | user
    --------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------------+------
     a98a98d5-5710-431b-a23d-d78ece882763 | 2015-04-28 19:18:34-0400 |   False |  net | updated |  {'prio': None, 'type_id': u'A', 'auth': None, 'is_free': False, 'ttl': 300L, 'active': True, 'domain_id': 32L, 'ordername': None, 'name': u'myrecord.mytable.net', 'created': '2015-04-14 17:44:23+00:00', 'modified': '2015-04-29 03:18:34.159619+00:00', 'id': 143L, 'content': u'192.213.216.16', 'change_date': 1430277514, 'owner_id': 20L} |   Record | update_a_record |   20
     893e9600-3d57-4b82-bdfd-41586023a90f | 2015-04-28 19:21:01-0400 |   False |  net | updated | {'prio': None, 'type_id': u'A', 'auth': None, 'is_free': False, 'ttl': 300L, 'active': True, 'domain_id': 32L, 'ordername': None, 'name': u'myrecord.mytable.net', 'created': '2015-04-14 17:44:23+00:00', 'modified': '2015-04-29 03:21:01.414393+00:00', 'id': 143L, 'content': u'192.213.15.16', 'change_date': 1430277661, 'owner_id': 20L} |   Record | update_a_record |   20
     f951b3ec-092a-4e9e-95c5-a6dce3363c29 | 2015-04-28 19:18:35-0400 |   False |  net | updated | {'prio': None, 'type_id': u'A', 'auth': None, 'is_free': False, 'ttl': 300L, 'active': True, 'domain_id': 32L, 'ordername': None, 'name': u'myrecord.mytable.net', 'created': '2015-04-14 17:44:23+00:00', 'modified': '2015-04-29 03:18:35.199869+00:00', 'id': 143L, 'content': u'192.213.15.16', 'change_date': 1430277515, 'owner_id': 20L} |   Record | update_a_record |   20
     db60ac52-39e9-4b46-accb-28a34b10579c | 2015-04-28 19:18:37-0400 |   False |  net | updated | {'prio': None, 'type_id': u'A', 'auth': None, 'is_free': False, 'ttl': 300L, 'active': True, 'domain_id': 32L, 'ordername': None, 'name': u'myrecord.mytable.net', 'created': '2015-04-14 17:44:23+00:00', 'modified': '2015-04-29 03:18:37.650135+00:00', 'id': 143L, 'content': u'192.213.15.16', 'change_date': 1430277517, 'owner_id': 20L} |   Record | update_a_record |   20
     336acc47-6a93-4ff9-a6c5-d29d3b2c4e35 | 2015-04-28 19:23:24-0400 |   False |  net | updated | {'prio': None, 'type_id': u'A', 'auth': None, 'is_free': False, 'ttl': 300L, 'active': True, 'domain_id': 32L, 'ordername': None, 'name': u'myrecord.mytable.net', 'created': '2015-04-14 17:44:23+00:00', 'modified': '2015-04-29 03:23:24.146505+00:00', 'id': 143L, 'content': u'192.213.15.16', 'change_date': 1430277804, 'owner_id': 20L} |   Record | update_a_record |   20
     4ca66f70-36cb-47cc-9324-6a5747d6a592 | 2015-04-28 19:18:48-0400 |   False |  net | updated | {'prio': None, 'type_id': u'A', 'auth': None, 'is_free': False, 'ttl': 300L, 'active': True, 'domain_id': 32L, 'ordername': None, 'name': u'myrecord.mytable.net', 'created': '2015-04-14 17:44:23+00:00', 'modified': '2015-04-29 03:18:48.242689+00:00', 'id': 143L, 'content': u'192.213.15.16', 'change_date': 1430277528, 'owner_id': 20L} |   Record | update_a_record |   20
     dbfda8bc-f6f2-4b97-b3c1-ccaff21338bb | 2015-04-28 19:18:32-0400 |   False |  net | updated | {'prio': None, 'type_id': u'A', 'auth': None, 'is_free': False, 'ttl': 300L, 'active': True, 'domain_id': 32L, 'ordername': None, 'name': u'myrecord.mytable.net', 'created': '2015-04-14 17:44:23+00:00', 'modified': '2015-04-29 03:18:32.857508+00:00', 'id': 143L, 'content': u'192.213.15.16', 'change_date': 1430277512, 'owner_id': 20L} |   Record | update_a_record |   20
     6c05779a-d3b8-40ac-84ee-af91a3bf6b15 | 2015-04-28 19:18:47-0400 |   False |  net | updated |  {'prio': None, 'type_id': u'A', 'auth': None, 'is_free': False, 'ttl': 300L, 'active': True, 'domain_id': 32L, 'ordername': None, 'name': u'myrecord.mytable.net', 'created': '2015-04-14 17:44:23+00:00', 'modified': '2015-04-29 03:18:47.181657+00:00', 'id': 143L, 'content': u'192.213.216.16', 'change_date': 1430277527, 'owner_id': 20L} |   Record | update_a_record |   20
     a037fb9d-cb58-4994-baad-88c441429199 | 2015-04-28 19:18:31-0400 |   False |  net | updated |  {'prio': None, 'type_id': u'A', 'auth': None, 'is_free': False, 'ttl': 300L, 'active': True, 'domain_id': 32L, 'ordername': None, 'name': u'myrecord.mytable.net', 'created': '2015-04-14 17:44:23+00:00', 'modified': '2015-04-29 03:18:31.680786+00:00', 'id': 143L, 'content': u'192.213.216.16', 'change_date': 1430277511, 'owner_id': 20L} |   Record | update_a_record |   20
     66ee42af-6770-4ef8-a300-764246ccc8ff | 2015-04-28 19:20:33-0400 |   False |  net | updated | {'prio': None, 'type_id': u'A', 'auth': None, 'is_free': False, 'ttl': 300L, 'active': True, 'domain_id': 32L, 'ordername': None, 'name': u'myrecord.mytable.net', 'created': '2015-04-14 17:44:23+00:00', 'modified': '2015-04-29 03:20:33.336544+00:00', 'id': 143L, 'content': u'192.213.15.16', 'change_date': 1430277633, 'owner_id': 20L} |   Record | update_a_record |   20
```

What I don't understand is that it doesn't order by the created_at column in a descending order.
My end goal is to store the logs of my app in this table and then be able to only show a few of them in a dashboard that is why I do a limit of 10.

What am I doing wrong here?
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I don't understand is that it doesn't order by the created_at column in a descending order.

Because Cassandra will only enforce a clustering order within a partition key.  Your partition key is `id`.  But that looks like it has an almost unique level of cardinality.  So unique, that if you partition on it you won't have any data to within to make sorting worthwhile.

```
SELECT *  FROM mytable.log  
WHERE "created_at" <= '2015-04-29 00:00:00' AND "user" = 20 LIMIT 10;
```

To satisfy this query, you should create a separate query table partitioned by `user`, such as `logByUser`.  You'll want that table to have the same columns, but with a PRIMARY KEY definition like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (user, created_at, id)
```

This PRIMARY KEY definition will allow the following query to function as you expect:

```
SELECT *  FROM mytable.logByUser  
WHERE "created_at" <= '2015-04-29 00:00:00' AND "user" = 20 LIMIT 10;
```

Also, I'd like to point out two things:

1. Cassandra functions best when you design your data model to fit your query patterns.  That may mean creating a table for each query.  As crazy as this might sound, creating five or six tables to suit each of your potential queries will perform **much** better than adding 5 secondary indexes to one table.
2. Secondary indexes are meant for convenience, not performance.  Their use is a known Cassandra anti-pattern.  Using them on low-cardinality columns (especially booleans) is asking for trouble.  They are not intended as a "magic bullet" to bridge the shortcomings of your data model.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I have to create a new table with these columns (user, created_at, id) and then query this table instead. This means in a code perspective that I have to make a double insert. One for the raw data and one for my query. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: @DoRivard Correct.  You can also batch your inserts together to provide some atomicity.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll look into implementing that today and I will let you know. I'll use this http://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/queryset.html#batch-queries to try the batch you are talking about. Thanks again.

Comment: I created this table: CREATE TABLE log_dash_board (
        id UUID,
        created_at timestamp,
        user int,
        PRIMARY KEY(id, created_at, user)
    ); // no clusering with order by desc
The problem is that I am getting the error: A column of a clustering key can be restricted only if the preceding one is restricted by an Equal relation.
You need to restrict created_at before restrict user.
The query: SELECT *  FROM   log_dash_board
WHERE "created_at" <= '2015-04-30 00:00:00' AND "user" = 20 LIMIT 10;

Thanks

Comment: By the way the insert with batch works perfectly it is still the ordering filtering that is my main issue. Thanks

Comment: @DoRivard check your table's PRIMARY KEY.  For your query to work, it should be `PRIMARY KEY (user, created_at, id)`...in that order.